# Do not hide shaded window bars

Tags: unity, window-manager

I configured Unity to shade the window on mouse double click and then the shaded window title bar hides and you can only see on the unity launcher with a small triangle that the application is launched.

Is it possible to configure Unity to NOT hide the shaded window title bar?